# Variables inside Windows batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file

I would like to pass a variable inside a for loop in a batch file:

```
echo TEST results >MYTest.log
set TEST_1=MYtestA
set TEST_2=MYtestB
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,2) DO (
 ECHO %%A
 echo  Building ???%TEST%_%%A
 ....
)
```

Bat I don't know how to pass inside the for loop the variable TEST_1 TEST_2 in order to have the following result:

```
Building MYtestA
Building MYtestB
```

Thanks Mariano

Answer (score 2):

You need delayed expansion of the variables. Then, use your `for` variable to compose the name of the variable you want to retrieve, and use delayed expansion with that name to get the content of the variable.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set TEST_1=MYtest1
set TEST_2=MYtest2

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,2) DO (
 ECHO %%A
 echo  Building !TEST_%%A!

)
```